# Advice on making Python code more concise

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and have just finished writing a program that allows a user to find the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence. I have tested it and it appears to work as intended. My question is how can I make my code more concise or more pythonic. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
values = [0,1]
n1 = 2

while True:                      # input and loop to limit the input range.
    try:
        n = int(input('Please enter position of fibonacci sequence you wish to know.'))
        break
    except:
        print('That\'s not a valid input')

if n < 3:                                #calculation block
    print (n)

else:
    while n1 != n:
        n2 = values[0] + values[1]
        values[0] = values[1]
        values[1] = n2
        n1 +=1

    print (n2)
```

Comment: This might be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Using functions would make your code more "pythonic" - Conciseness may not be your first priority:

```
def get_user_input():
    while True:                      # input and loop to limit the input range.
        try:
            n = int(input('Please enter position of fibonacci sequence you wish to know.'))
            return n
        except:
            print('That\'s not a valid input')


def get_nth_fib_number(nth):
    values = [0, 1]

    current_fib = 2

    while current_fib <= nth:
        values.append(values[-2] + values[-1])
        current_fib += 1

    return values[nth]

get_nth_fib_number(get_user_input())
```